# html with css convert to word doc using php

Tags: javascript, php, html, graph, charts

I need to convert Graph html with css to word file.This is my code.i need to export word docment file .

```
<?php
 include("html_to_doc.inc.php");

$content = '<div id="piechart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px; position: relative;">
            <div dir="ltr" style="position: relative; width: 900px; height: 500px;">
            <div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 100%; height:         100%;"><svg width="900" height="500" style="overflow: hidden;"><defs id="defs"></defs>
            <rect x="0" y="0" width="900" height="500" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#ffffff"></rect><g><rect x="542" y="96" width="198" height="37" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill-opacity="0" fill="#ffffff"></rect><g><rect x="542" y="96" width="198" height="14" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill-opacity="0" fill="#ffffff"></rect><g><text text-anchor="start" x="561" y="107.9" font-family="Arial" font-size="14" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#222222">male</text></g><rect x="542" y="96" width="14" height="14" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#3366cc"></rect></g><g><rect x="542" y="119" width="198" height="14" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill-opacity="0" fill="#ffffff"></rect><g><text text-anchor="start" x="561" y="130.9" font-family="Arial" font-size="14" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#222222">femle</text></g><rect x="542" y="119" width="14" height="14" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#dc3912"></rect></g></g><g><path d="M340,251L266.7041014722907,386.4389576857993A154,154,0,0,1,340,97L340,251A0,0,0,0,0,340,251" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="1" fill="#dc3912"></path><text text-anchor="start" x="204.75670248578234" y="226.71643359920404" font-family="Arial" font-size="14" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#ffffff">42.1%</text></g>
<g><path d="M340,251L340,97A154,154,0,1,1,266.7041014722907,386.4389576857993L340,251A0,0,0,1,0,340,251" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="1" fill="#3366cc"></path>
<text text-anchor="start" x="435.24329751421766" y="285.083566400796" font-family="Arial" font-size="14" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#ffffff">57.9%</text></g><g></g></svg></div></div><div style="display: none; position: absolute; top: 510px; left: 910px; white-space: nowrap; font-family: Arial; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold;">8 (42.1%)</div><div></div></div>';
$f_name="test.doc";
$my_file = 'export_doc_html.html';
$handle = fopen($my_file, 'w') or die('Cannot open file:  '.$my_file);
$data = $content;
fwrite($handle, $data);
$htmltodoc= new HTML_TO_DOC();
$htmltodoc->createDoc("export_doc_html.html",$f_name);
//$htmltodoc->createDocFromURL("http://yahoo.com","test");
?>
```

Comment: So, what's the problem? We are not going to guess what problem you are having. Nor will we write the whole thing for you. Please state the problem with the code and then we can help.

Comment: What does the HTML_TO_DOC class actually do?